# Webpack, sass, Import css with url

Tags: sass, webpack

I import a css file with a font-face declared in it with a relative URL.

```
@import '~materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min';

.register-container {
  @extend .row;
}
```

I use the raw-loader!sass-loader chain because it's an angular component style.

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: PathHelper.getPathFromRoot('src', 'app', 'modules'),
    loader: 'raw!sass'
},
```

When I do that the content of the materialize file is being copied. And when I load the page it tries to load the fonts from a wrong directory because the relative path is wrong.

The fonts work because I load them with different loaders chain in a different file. The chain is: css!resolve-url!sass?sourceMap

So the fonts are there but the issue is that the content of the css is copied twice and it loads the fonts multiple times from a front path

Can I do something about it? So that the sass loader will know not to copy the css content?

Answer (score 0):

Might Help?

```
$font-url: unquote("somefile.css");
@if variable-exists(font-url) {
  @import url($font-url);
} @else {
  @error "sorry no dice";
}
```

**String Functions**

```
unquote($string)
```

Removes quotes from a string.

```
- (Sass::Script::Value::String) unquote($string)
```

Removes quotes from a string. If the string is already unquoted, this will return it unmodified.

**Examples:**

```
unquote("foo") => foo
unquote(foo) => foo
```

Comment: what file should i put in the unquote in my example?

Comment: yes I know what `unquote` does. I just can't figure out what url should I put inside of it